# CubeMX freeRTOS V9 crashes on STM32F4

Tags: freertos, stm32f4, cubemx

I have a specific issue with freeRTOS on STM32F4 using cubeMX. When I'm using the older version of CubeMX (with package support e.g. STM32Cube_FW_F4_V1.14.0) which supports the freeRTOSv8, it works nicely, no issues. When I updated the CubeMX to latest version that supports freeRTOSv9, it crashes when it trays to run the RTOS scheduler

```
    BaseType_t xPortStartScheduler( void )
{
    /* configMAX_SYSCALL_INTERRUPT_PRIORITY must not be set to 0.
    See http://www.FreeRTOS.org/RTOS-Cortex-M3-M4.html */
    configASSERT( configMAX_SYSCALL_INTERRUPT_PRIORITY );

    /* This port can be used on all revisions of the Cortex-M7 core other than
    the r0p1 parts.  r0p1 parts should use the port from the
    /source/portable/GCC/ARM_CM7/r0p1 directory. */
    configASSERT( portCPUID != portCORTEX_M7_r0p1_ID );
    configASSERT( portCPUID != portCORTEX_M7_r0p0_ID );

    #if( configASSERT_DEFINED == 1 )
    {
        volatile uint32_t ulOriginalPriority;
        volatile uint8_t * const pucFirstUserPriorityRegister = ( volatile uint8_t * const ) ( portNVIC_IP_REGISTERS_OFFSET_16 + portFIRST_USER_INTERRUPT_NUMBER );
        volatile uint8_t ucMaxPriorityValue;

        /* Determine the maximum priority from which ISR safe FreeRTOS API
        functions can be called.  ISR safe functions are those that end in
        "FromISR".  FreeRTOS maintains separate thread and ISR API functions to
        ensure interrupt entry is as fast and simple as possible.

        Save the interrupt priority value that is about to be clobbered. */
        ulOriginalPriority = *pucFirstUserPriorityRegister;

        /* Determine the number of priority bits available.  First write to all
        possible bits. */
        *pucFirstUserPriorityRegister = portMAX_8_BIT_VALUE;

        /* Read the value back to see how many bits stuck. */
        ucMaxPriorityValue = *pucFirstUserPriorityRegister;

        /* Use the same mask on the maximum system call priority. */
        ucMaxSysCallPriority = configMAX_SYSCALL_INTERRUPT_PRIORITY & ucMaxPriorityValue;

        /* Calculate the maximum acceptable priority group value for the number
        of bits read back. */
        ulMaxPRIGROUPValue = portMAX_PRIGROUP_BITS;
        while( ( ucMaxPriorityValue & portTOP_BIT_OF_BYTE ) == portTOP_BIT_OF_BYTE )
        {
            ulMaxPRIGROUPValue--;
            ucMaxPriorityValue <<= ( uint8_t ) 0x01;
        }

        /* Shift the priority group value back to its position within the AIRCR
        register. */
        ulMaxPRIGROUPValue <<= portPRIGROUP_SHIFT;
        ulMaxPRIGROUPValue &= portPRIORITY_GROUP_MASK;

        /* Restore the clobbered interrupt priority register to its original
        value. */
        *pucFirstUserPriorityRegister = ulOriginalPriority;
    }
    #endif /* conifgASSERT_DEFINED */

    /* Make PendSV and SysTick the lowest priority interrupts. */
    portNVIC_SYSPRI2_REG |= portNVIC_PENDSV_PRI;
    portNVIC_SYSPRI2_REG |= portNVIC_SYSTICK_PRI;

    /* Start the timer that generates the tick ISR.  Interrupts are disabled
    here already. */
    vPortSetupTimerInterrupt();

    /* Initialise the critical nesting count ready for the first task. */
    uxCriticalNesting = 0;

    /* Ensure the VFP is enabled - it should be anyway. */
    vPortEnableVFP();

    /* Lazy save always. */
    *( portFPCCR ) |= portASPEN_AND_LSPEN_BITS;

    /* Start the first task. */
    prvPortStartFirstTask();

    /* Should never get here as the tasks will now be executing!  Call the task
    exit error function to prevent compiler warnings about a static function
    not being called in the case that the application writer overrides this
    functionality by defining configTASK_RETURN_ADDRESS. */
    prvTaskExitError();

    /* Should not get here! */
    return 0;
}
/*-----------------------------------------------------------*/
```

it crashes during the first task start **prvPortStartFirstTask();**

Comment: I recreated a new CubeMx project from scratch after updating. SVC_Handler and PendSV_Handler were declared at 2 different places and they would reappear every time I regenerated the code. If you don't need anything from the new version, go back to the old one.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `PendSV_Handler`, `SVC_Handler` or `SysTick_Handler` interrupt handlers is not implemented. Please check stm32f4xx_it.c and FreeRTOSConfig.h files. Usually interrupts connected by defines:

```
#define vPortSVCHandler SVC_Handler
#define xPortPendSVHandler PendSV_Handler
#define xPortSysTickHandler SysTick_Handler
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you worked with STM32F4 board, it's Cortex-M4 MCU, it could be much easier to debug if you can provide Cortex-M4 registers value when the program stops running, the registers' value like `control`, `xPSR`, `sp`, `lr`, `pc`, and `CFSR` and dump exception stack frame, then check if these values make sense with the RTOS disassembly code.

In FreeRTOS port for Cortex-M4, the final step of `prvPortStartFirstTask()` is to generate SVC exception, then CPU jumps to SVC handler routine. Before the SVC exception, FreeRTOS even haven't started running the first task.

So in your case CPU is unlikely to halt in `PendSV_Handler` and `SysTick_Handler`, It's more likely to get stuck on fault handler routine (e.g. HardFault, or MemManage fault, if you turn on MPU of your STM32F4 board). If you use GDB, you can add breakpoints on this fault handler routine `HardFault_Handler`, `MemManage_Handler` to figure out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As specified over [this post](https://community.st.com/s/question/0D53W00000DhHba/bug-nucleo-stm32-f401re-freertos-stm32cubemx-140-hardfault), it's a known issue on STM32F401 plateform when using STM32CubeMX or STM32CubeIDE device configuration tool.

**Solution**

Within your STMCubeMX project, look for *stm32f4xx_hal_msp.c* file. Then, replace the line `HAL_NVIC_SetPriorityGrouping(NVIC_PRIORITYGROUP_0);` by `HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(PendSV_IRQn, 15, 0);`